# How to Run the Card Script Without Switching to that Card in Livecode?

Tags: startup, livecode

I have a livecode project with five cards.
First card has one label "label1",
Second card has two labels "Greeting" and "Word",
Third card has a button "button1",
Fourth card has a textbox "text1",
and the fifth card has a label "HelloWord".

My goal is to display "Hello" to all controls mentioned above.

I have this code in every card

Card 1

```
on openCard
put "Hello" to field "label1"
end openCard
```

Card 2

```
on openCard
put "Hello" to field "Greeting"
put "Hello" to field "Word"
end openCard
```

Card 3

```
on openCard
put "Hello" to button "button1"
end openCard
```

Card 4

```
on openCard
put "Hello" to field "text1"
end openCard
```

Card 5

```
on openCard
put "Hello" to field "HelloWord"
end openCard
```

Mainstack

```
on openStack
go to card "card1"
go to card "card2"
go to card "card3"
go to card "card4"
go to card "card5"
end openStack
```

These codes are working.

But I want the program to execute those `on openCard` scripts in every card on startup without going to another card.

I tried to execute those scripts in `on openStack` (without `go to card` scripts) but I got an error. The error says "can't find handler".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the code from the openCard handler to a different handler, e.g. `initializeCard`and call that handler from both the openCard and the openStack handlers. However, if a card executes a script and refers to objects on that card, you may get the `object not found` handler. Therefore, you need to refer to objects on the card explicitly, using `of me` or `of card <card name>`.

```
on openStack
  repeat with x = 1 to number of cards
    send "initializeCard`to card x
  end repeat
end openStack

// example for card 2
on initializeCard
  put "Hello" to field "Greeting" of me
  put "Hello" to field "Word" of me
end initializeCard
```

Your script that goes to all cards is also a good solution, but you might want to lock the screen, to make it look like you're not switching cards:

```
on openStack
  lock screen
  go cd "card1"
  go cd "card2"
  go cd "card3"
  go cd "card4"
  go cd "card5"
  go cd "card1"
  unlock screen
end openStack
```

Comment: Locking the screen could be effective in preparing the application such as loading screen. Thanks for your help.